# Custom Individual Content for Members

Tags: member-management

I want to know if the Expression Engine Member Management will allow me to create custom content for each individual member of my site?

For example, I would like to be able to upload documents and images for specific individual users.  If I uploaded photos for UserX, I want only UserX to be able to see those.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this - but simply you can use their member id and search based on that. Displaying different content accordingly. Maybe even a channel to query against relating that id to a document.

Liekwise you could maybe use a custom field within the member group, and then do the special content for each user there.

Or perhaps have a channel where you make the member the author. and then you upload your content under them as the author. in the template you query author to display as required.

So yes it can be done - but will take some thinking.
More complicated ways - programme a plugin, or maybe find one on devot-ee

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  This gives me enough direction to begin researching solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[I was going to comment but I don't have enough rep so I had to make a post.]

Kinda echo'ing what Nevsie-Modeten said.

I've done something similar to this using: 
http://www.ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/ 
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/visitor (ee3 version)

and also making a custom field type that lists members from another member group and on submit adds itself as a custom field to that member.